# How to use babel to transpile COMMONJS style module for React.js

Tags: reactjs, browserify, babeljs

All:

I am pretty new to React working flow, say if I have one module like:

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var Todo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <div>Hello there </div>;
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("div1"))
```

Could anyone show me an work-flow guideline(like step by step tutorial) about how to transpile -> include -> debug, I find a lot posts about browserify/babel, but when I tried to transpile( using `npm install babel-preset-react` and then `"browserify ./app.js -o bundle.js -t babelify --presets react"` ) , it always give some error like:

```
SyntaxError: C:/Temp/web/lnreact/app.js: Unexpected token (10:9)
   8 | var Todo = React.createClass({
   9 |  render: function() {
> 10 |          return <div>Hello there </div>;
     |          ^
  11 |  }
  12 | });
  13 |
```

By now, only the gulp version works:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var browserify = require("browserify");
var babelify = require("babelify");
var source = require("vinyl-source-stream");


gulp.task("build", function(){
    return browserify({
        entries: "./app.js", 
        extensions: [".js"], 
        deug:true
    })
    .transform("babelify", {
        presets: ["react"]
    })
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source("bundle.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

But with this, I do not know how to debug( it gives me a bunch of code in one single file called bundle.js, there is no seperate files included for debug purpose even I specify debug: true in browserify).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is best to look at a starter project. This is a project that will demonstrate a basic working structure that you can use as a starting point for your own projects. Here is one that uses gulp/browserify/babel. https://github.com/calitek/BasicStarter.

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned in the question, if I use gulp, I have already get this project work, but the only thing missing is debug(there is only one very long bundle.js). Could you show me how to debug?

Comment: Which browser are you opening the page in? By the way, the project includes the node server.js.

Comment: I open that bundle.js in Chrome 46.  In source tab, there are just index and dist/bundle.js, I guess there should be app.js included, but not sure

Comment: You need the server side setup. I use node/express for my server setup. That's part of the starter kit, it gives you the whole client/server setup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for this but you can include [gulp-sourcemaps](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps) to help out.  Just `npm install gulp-sourcemap --save-dev` then include in your gulp file.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sourcemaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var babel = require("gulp-babel");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");

gulp.task("default", function () {
  return gulp.src("src/**/*.js")
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(concat("all.js"))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write("."))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

This will generate a `.map` file that you can use to debug.  In a nutshell, it shows where in your original source code the error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

[Browserify CLI](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) specifies that you should wrap the plugin + its arguments with square brackets.

Therefore, your command should probably be the following:

```
browserify ./app.js -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets react ]
```